# Add RAM to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to add memory to an ec2 micro instance that contains by default 1GB of RAM. Want to make it 2GB. Is it possible? Do I need to create a new instance or can I change an already existent instance?

Comment: You need to migrate to a different instance type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EC2 instances have a very specific configuration regarding CPU, RAM, local instance storage, etc.

It is not possible to alter that configuration.

If your application needs more RAM than a micro instance can give you, then you need to move to a different EC2 instance type.

For 2 GB of RAM, you can change your instance to a t2.small instance.

Comment: will it change the ip of the instance? or effect anyother setting?

Comment: Yes, it will change the ip of instance. You need to attach Elastic IP with your instance.

Answer (score 78):

Stop the instance. Change the instance type to the one that has the desired RAM and start the instance. You need t2.small for 2GB.

It goes without saying if you have an elastic IP assigned, stop/start will not change the IP. But if you have a (auto) public IP assigned, then the public IP will change after stop/start. If the machine is in a private subnet, then stop/start has no effect on the IP.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the data on the instance lost after restart?

Comment: @Shiva disk data will remain, not lost. If the instance had Instance store, it will be lost.

Comment: works like a charm.  thanks!

Comment: It will change the Public IP so be aware of that when you try to reconnect!

Comment: @sogu thanks for the crucial info, this should be part of the answers

Comment: @suno what about elastic IP?